# update query in mysql not working

Tags: mysql

Question is that I am having two rows for each employee and want to merge them into one.

Trying to run these queries without success. Could you help in figuring out the problem. All the field being used are non-constraints.

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.rfid = T2.rfid, 
    T1.genderid = T2.genderid 
from employee T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  employee T2 ON (T1.Code = T2.Code)
```

or

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.rfid = T2.rfid,
    T1.genderid = T2.genderid 
from employee T1, employee T2 
WHERE T1.Code = T2.Code
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbrOF.png)

Error being shown is:
MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use at line 3

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. Not sure about sintaxis. But I doubt you will get what you want that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a 
JOIN TABLE_B b 
  ON a.join_col = b.join_col 
SET a.column = b.column
```